# Java minesweeper game problem. hiding mines when the game begins?

Tags: java, algorithm, minesweeper

I've been able to successfully initiate a minefield when the game begins with 10 mines randomly scattered over the field. However, I'm having problems hiding these mines from the user when the game begins. As you know, the point of minesweeper is to find where the mines are WITHOUT being able to see them. I need help figuring out how to hide the mines.

Below is the code I have written for my Grid class which initiates the grid and includes a method which fills it with mines. How can I hide these mines and only reveal them when they are clicked on? Thanks for the help!

```
public class Grid {

 private int[][] grid;
 private boolean isHidden;
 private  int rows;
 private final int columns;
 private final int mines;


 public Grid() {
  this.rows = 8;
  this.columns = 8;
  this.mines = 10;
  this.grid = new int[rows][columns];

 }

 public int[][] getGrid() {
  return grid;
 }

 public int getRows() {
  return rows;
 }

 public int getColumns() {
  return columns;
  }

 public void fillGrid() {
  Random ranGen = new Random();

  for(int i = 0; i < this.mines; ) {
   int row = ranGen.nextInt(this.rows - 1);
   int column = ranGen.nextInt(this.columns - 1);

   if(grid[row][column] != MinesweeperGUI.MINE) {
    grid[row][column] = MinesweeperGUI.MINE;
    i++;
   }
  }
    }
```

Comment: This takes me back, I had to write Minesweeper in Java for a lab at uni.

Comment: Makes sense, this is a project assigned by the uni that I attend lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of methods. Easiest to implement here would be a 2d array of booleans: Opened and unopened. If not opened, show a closed square. Else, show what's there.

An alternative method would be to turn this more object oriented, and make a Tile class: it holds a boolean for a mine, and a enum for open/closed/flagged/question mark.

Comment: thank you! implementing the methods worked great. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should have two matrices: One for the mines (`MineMatrix`) and one to track the user clicks (`UserClickMatrix`).

You should only show the end user `UserClickMatrix` and initialize all the cells with `NotClicked` at the start of the game. Whenever the user clicks on a cell, change the status of the cell to `Clicked`. Then, grab the cell indices from `UserClickMatrix` and check against MineMatrix (`MineMatrix[clickedRow][clickedColumn] == MINE`). If the condition evaluates to TRUE, game ends.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't your grid matrix contains elements of the class GridElement? This GridElement class could have an property "bool visibile". An grid matrix of int's isn't so good. Think more OO.

Comment: I tried to implement this earlier, but we have a strict list of directions that we need to follow. I tried creating a Square class to represent the elements in the grid. Our professor is requiring us to have a 2d array of ints for the grid...quite stupid if you ask me.

Comment: Ur prof. thinks probally in C ^^. I should suggest the answer of Pimgd is the best.